# Using a Python list to populate in a drop down validation

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` to manipulate a spreadsheet from Python.

I am trying to create a drop-down validation in a workbook tab called `organisation`.  Is it possible to use a Python list to populate the elements in the drop down selection?

When I hardcode the drop down options to into the `DataValidation` line like so:

```
dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1="The", "earth", "revolves", "around", "sun", allow_blank=True)
```

The drop down is created in the spreadsheet tab and populated with the options as expected.

However when I try to add the drop down options using Python list and then pass to the `DataValidation` line like so:

```
    valid = ['"The,earth,revolves,around,sun"']
    dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=valid, allow_blank=True)
```

the drop down list is not created.

For extra information please see the full script:

```
def addValidationDropDowns(path):
        
    valid = ['"The,earth,revolves,around,sun"']
   
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb['organisation']
    dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1=valid, allow_blank=True)
    ws.add_data_validation(dv)
    for x in range(0, 3):
        dv.add(ws["A"+str(x+10)])
    
    wb.save(path)
    
    return
```

Comment: From the [Dokumentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validation.html?highlight=datavalidation): `dv = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Dog,Cat,Bat"', allow_blank=True)`. Use `valid = '"The,earth,revolves,around,sun"'`

Comment: `formula1=",".join(valid)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51501438/7919597

Answer (score 1):

I struggle with this the first time i did it. It is curious that if the 'type' paramater or DataValidation is "list" you think ¡ok, let's use a list! but no! it is expecting a string. I think your example will work if you remove the square brackets to the 'valid' variable.

`valid = '"The,earth,revolves,around,sun"'`